# How to automatically add all files/folder of application when using a Smart Device CAB Project?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, windows-mobile, windows-mobile-6.5, cab

I have founding lot of difficulty in a Smart Device CAB Project. I have created an application in Windows Mobile 6.5. Then I have created a CAB project. But it's pain for me to manually add folder/files in the project. I there is any way to automatically add all files/folder of application when using a Smart Device CAB Project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your **Setup and Deployment** project, select "Add > Project Output..." and select the files you want included in your project.

[image: screenshot1]

[image: screenshot2]